# elisp Invalid function: (quote a)

Tags: elisp

As i am newbie for elisp language, I code the below code for elisp.

when i eval that, it is failed.

echo area show the error "our-member: Invalid function: (quote a)"

Also i am confusing about the basic element for lisp language.

is that `'a` not a obj or a list ? And what is the list definition due to i dont find that on wiki and google.

```
(defun our-member(obj list)
  (if (nil list)
      nil
    (if (eql (car list) obj)
        list
      (our-member obj (cdr list)))))

(our-member('a '(a b c)))
```

Comment: The function to check for a `nil` value is called `null`.  Your code could be simplified to `(if (or (null list) (eql (car list) obj)) list ...`

Comment: @tripleee yes, i already find that function is null nor nil. thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function call in Lisp looks like `(function arguments)` not `(function (arguments))`.  The latter, you'll recognize, is attempting to run `arguments` as a function as well.

Emacs comes with excellent documentation; Lisp's data types are documented at http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lisp-Data-Types.html but maybe start with the gentler introduction, which also covers basic syntax; https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/eintr.html